# C++ Polymorphic behaviour with global array of Base Class type

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism

Why is the code below able to demonstrate polymorphic behaviour

```
TwoDShapes* s2d[2];

int main()
{
    Circle c1(/*parameter*/);
    Rectangle s1(/*parameter*/);

    s2d[0] = &c1;
    s2d[1] = &s1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        cout << s2d[i]->toString() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

BUT the code below throws an error

```
void test(); 

TwoDShapes* s2d[2];

int main()
{
    test();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        cout << s2d[i]->toString() << endl;

    return 0;
}

void test()
{
    Circle c1(/*parameter*/);
    Rectangle s1(/*parameter*/);

    s2d[0] = &c1;
    s2d[1] = &s1;
}
```

I noticed that when I try to initialise the contents of the array within another function other than main(), the Base class'(TwoDShapes) toString() method gets invoked instead of the Derived classes'(Circle and Rectangle) toString() method.
But when I do the same thing within main(), it is able to display polymorphic behaviour.

Below is my Base and Derived classes

```
// Base Class
class TwoDShapes
{
public:
    TwoDShapes();
    virtual string toString();

string TwoDShapes::toString()
{
    return "Inside Base Class toString method";
}

// Derived classes
class Circle : public TwoDShapes
{
public:
    Circle(/*parameter*/);
    string toString() override;
};

string Circle::toString()
{
    return "Inside Circle toString method";
}
```

*Edit 1: Included a more complete code

Comment: Well, you obviously haven't shown us *all* your code but - do you have a declaration of `test()` somewhere before its invocation in `main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c1` and `s1` are local variables to function `test`.
The moment it finishes, you can no longer access them.

So, `s2d[i]` contains a pointer to some local variable of test function. By the time this code `cout << s2d[i]->toString() << endl;` runs, the test function already terminated. So all local variables are destroyed. Calling `toString()` function of a destroyed object has undefined behavior. You can no longer access them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `test` function, where you create two **local** objects (`c1` and `s1`) and save their addresses. However, when that function returns, those two objects' lifetimes will end, and the `s2d[0]` and `s2d[1]` values will be [dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the mention of dangling pointers. I will go and read up on that.